# Is the "deferred" example from the App Engine docs thread-safe?

Tags: google-app-engine

Would this code from https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred be threadsafe ? (useable with `runtime: python27` + `threadsafe: yes`)

```
class GuestbookUpdater(Mapper):
    KIND = Greeting

    def map(self, entity):
        if entity.content.lower().find('foo') != -1:
            entity.content += ' Bar!'
            return ([entity], [])
       return ([], [])
  mapper = MyMapper()
  deferred.defer(mapper.run)
```

also, shoudln´t it read

```
class GuestbookUpdater(Mapper):
    KIND = Greeting

    def map(self, entity):
        if entity.content.lower().find('foo') != -1:
            entity.content += ' Bar!'
            return ([entity], [])
       return ([], [])

mapper = GuestbookUpdater()
deferred.defer(mapper.run)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment in the top example on that page explains that the calling of defer should happen 'somewhere else', and that applies to the later examples as well - it shouldn't be at the top-level of the package as you have it though, or it will get called whenever the package is imported! Put those lines in a request handler method, which you can then visit via your browser to trigger the job.

Comment: Yea, I´d put `mapper = GuestbookUpdater()
deferred.defer(mapper.run)` in the request handler and GuestbookUpdater in a import or above in the request handler depending on the size of the function.